# selector in IE7

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm using css2 to implement some fixes for IE7 on a website.

So I have to put `margin-top:30px` and `margin-bottom:-30px` a `<h2>` title but I dind't find right selector.

```
<div class="ui-content">
    <h2>Text</h2>
    <ul class="ui-listview">
        List Items
    </ul>
</div>
```

The fact is that Everytime there is a `H2` followed by a `UL`, I must put those two properties, so I wanted to do a selector with h2 and ul, but I don't know wich ones...

Thanks to help me

Comment: You can't select the `h2` based on the existence of the `ul`. You can do it the other way round using the `h2+ul` or `h2~ul`, but those select the `ul`, not the `h2`.

Comment: To be honest, I would stop worrying about minor layout issues in IE7. Is it really a problem if the page looks a bit different to IE7 users? As long as it's fully usable, you should be happy with the result and leave it at that. The few people still using IE7 won't know the difference, and probably won't care about it anyway. Ask yourself how much time you're spending to fix IE7-specific issues, vs how many IE7 users you're actually going to have. The odds are you've already wasted more time than it's worth.

Comment: I know but I'm not the client ;-)

Comment: Sometimes it's okay to educate the client. If that's not an option, you should at least be charging them extra to support old browsers. *"Site design $xxx. Add 5% to include support for IE8. Add another 15% to support IE7. Add another 30% to support IE6."* People usually get the message, especially if you also include real-world usage stats for IE7 ([0.4% browser share currently](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201207-201307)).

Answer (score 0):

You can't select h2s followed by uls but you can do it the other way round. E.g.

```
h2 + ul { /*your css to style the ul*/ }
```

So you could put fixes/negative margins or whatever on the ul?

Answer (score 0):

This is a only-ie-7 selector:

```
IE 7 only
 *:first-child+html h2 {}
```

Anyhow, I don't recommend it because almost no one uses this browser anymore, so neither should you program specially for it.

Answer (score 0):

> Everytime there is a H2 followed by a UL, I must put those two properties, so I wanted to do a selector with h2 and ul

As stated by @Spudley and @Coop, you can't select an element that is followed by another element (except rare cases with series of li or td or th and `:nth-last-child()` but it's more of a trick).
The closest thing you can do in pure CSS is testing if h2 is followed by (an)other element(s) or not, i.e. if it's *not* alone with `:only-child` pseudo.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aonly-child):

> The `:only-child` CSS pseudo-class represents any element which is the only child of its parent. This is the same as `:first-child:last-child` or `:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(1)`, but with a lower specificity.

Support is IE9+ so if you want to style this element in IE7 and IE8 too (or in the precise case where it's followed by ul but not p or h3...), you'll need JavaScript or to add a class server-side and style this class.

```
.ui-content > h2:not(:only-child) {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}
```

EDIT:
You can also test if H2 is both the `:first-child` and the second-to-last child of its parent so it'll be styled if it's followed by whatever element but not if this second element has other siblings (third, fourth one, etc)

```
.ui-content > h2:first-child:nth-last-of-type(2) {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}
```

Simplest code would be ;)

```
<div class="ui-content">
    <h2 class="followed-by-list">Text</h2>
    <ul class="ui-listview">
        List Items
    </ul>
</div>

.followed-by-list {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}
```

---

Other trick that'd mean a complete overhaul of your project (say, for next project ;) ): never set a single `margin-bottom` to content elements (I mean h2, ul, p, etc. It's OK for div and below "blocks") and always set a margin-top to:

- an element (general case) ex: p
- if needed, an element coming after another like `elt1 + p` would have a certain margin-top, `elt2 + p` another one, etc